# How can i add cover image on mp3 file using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to convert audio file to mp3 and I want to add cover image into mp3 file.
I tried this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "input audio file" -i image.png out.mp3
```

When conversion completes there is no cover image into mp3. 
I tried and this which is from the official documentation of ffmpeg. The result is the same mp3 file without cover image.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i cover.png -c copy -metadata:s:v title="Album cover"-metadata:s:v comment="Cover (Front)" out.mp3
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of FFmpeg are you using?  Are there any messages in the output during conversion that suggest possible problems?  (It may be easiest to simply post the entire output from the command.)

Comment: ffmpeg version N-31461-g371888c, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers

Comment: The result is mp3 file without image in it.
ffmpeg.exe -i "input audio file" -i image.png out.mp3
Result is: video:0kB audio:2234kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.019186%